# Type variable can only be introduced in match if it's lower-case?

Tags: scala, generics

While trying to understand some code, I've run into strange behaviour and reduced it to this:

Introducing type parameter in a match doesn't work:

```
scala> Some(0) match { case _: Some[A] => 0 }
<console>:8: error: not found: type A
              Some(0) match { case _: Some[A] => 0 }
                                           ^
```

However, if I make it lower-case, it does:

```
scala> Some(0) match { case _: Some[a] => 0 }
res2: Int = 0
```

Is this a bug in Scala or is there an explanation I am missing?

Comment: Though @travis is completely right with what he said, but I think in this case the issue is different.

The compiler is simply not finding the type `A` in the current scope. `Some[a]` works because in this case `a` is taken as a type variable. And because at runtime it is erased so `a` is `Any`.

Comment: @Jatin: That's what I said! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the same thing with value variables in patterns:

```
scala> Some(0) match { case A => 0 }
<console>:8: error: not found: value A
              Some(0) match { case A => 0 }
                                   ^

scala> Some(0) match { case a => 0 }
res1: Int = 0
```

If you want to introduce a variable (either at the value or type level) in a pattern, you have to use a lower case identifier—there's simply no way to introduce an upper case variable. Note that going the other direction is possible—if you want to match against the value of a lower case variable, you can surround it with back quotes.

From [the language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf%E2%80%8E) (discussing a change introduced in 2.3):

> The syntax of types in patterns has been refined (§8.2). Scala now
>   distinguishes be- tween type variables (starting with a lower case
>   letter) and types as type arguments in patterns. Type variables are
>   bound in the pattern. Other type arguments are, as in previous
>   versions, erased.

So no, not a bug, although it's arguably a pretty confusing language design decision.

Comment: One question. This works `type A = whatever;  Some(0) match { case _: Some[A] => 0 }`. But if we replace `Some[A]` with `Some[a]`, it still works but `a` is not defined any where. What role is `a` playing here?

Comment: Since `a` is lower case it introduces a variable—it doesn't need to be defined outside of the match (and in fact if there is an `a` outside of the match it'll be shadowed).

Comment: I knew how this works on the value level quite well, but for some reason didn't realise it would also apply on the type level.